# Calling AuraEnabled function from VisualForce

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, aura

Issue is I have a Apex Controlled being used in lightning components. I want to reuse the same function from Visual Force page.

1. Can I call a AuraEnabled Function from VisualForce Page. 
   OR
2. Can I call a lightning component from Visual Force Page.

Answer (score 4):

1. Yes You can call AuraEnabled Function from VisualForce Page just like apex others method.
2. Yes You can Use lightning from Visualforce Page

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_visualforce.htm